# jQuery flot chart - change labels (ticks) of y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I need to be able to change the labels/ticks of a (horizontal) bar chart based on another array full of labels. - this is part of a name resolver thingy.

So my initalization code looks around the lines of so:

```js
var ticks = [
  ["abc", 0],
  ["def", 1],
  ["ghi", 2],
  ["jkl", 3]
];

//loop for each value goes here
var data = {
  data: [
    [0, 111],
    [1, 222],
    [2, 333],
    [3, 444]
  ], //... etc
  bars: {
    horizontal: true,
    show: true,
    barWidth: 0.8,
    align: "center"
  }
};

var plot = $.plot($("#graph"), data, {
  yaxis: {
    ticks: ticks
  }
  //etc
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.flotcharts.org/javascript/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart" id="graph" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Is there any way of updating the bar chart without destroying old graph and then creating a new one? - so something like this?:

```
//New ticks for y-axis
plot.yaxisticks = [["ABC", 0], ["DEF", 1], ["GHI", 2], ["JKL", 3]];
plot.draw();
```

EDIT:
So I can set the values through `plot.getOptions().yaxis.ticks[i][1] = value` but it seems like it cannot re-draw the ticks using `plot.setupGrid()`. Help?

Comment: It seems that the getOptions() method does not actually change the values for the labels/ticks on redraw. I bet if you change other values such as the max and min - they would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels can be changed through `plot.getAxes().yaxis.options.ticks`, then redrawing the plot.

```
function test() {
    var ticks = plot.getAxes().yaxis.options.ticks;

    for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++ ){
        ticks[i][1] += " test";
    }

    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.draw();
}
```

The above code will add " test" to the end of the label.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify ticks array for yaxis.

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes

```js
$(function () {
    
    var ticks = [[0, "abc"], [1, "def"], [2, "ghi"], [3, "jkl"], [4, "four"]];
    var data = [[111, 1], [222, 2], [333, 3],  [444, 4]];
    
    var plot1 = $.plot($("#graph"), [{ data: data, label: "Series A"}], {
    series: {
        legend : {
            show: true
        },
        bars: {
         horizontal: true,
         show: true,
         barWidth: 0.8,
         align: "center"
      },
        points : {
            show : true
        }
    },
    yaxis : {
        ticks: ticks
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.flotcharts.org/javascript/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart" id="graph" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `#graph` container div element are further div elements which contain the labels. You can access and change these directly in the DOM without using the `setupGrid()` method. But you should also change the values in the options to keep them in sync.

The label div elements look something like this:

```
<div class="tickLabels" style="font-size:smaller">
    <div class="xAxis x1Axis" style="color:#545454">
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:-44px;top:761px;width:138px">1</div>
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:841px;top:761px;width:138px">2</div>
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1726px;top:761px;width:138px">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="yAxis y1Axis" style="color:#545454">
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:749px;right:1781px;width:18px">0</div>
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:393px;right:1781px;width:18px">10</div>
        <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:37px;right:1781px;width:18px">20</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To change the text of the labels use something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
    $('#graph div.y1axis div.tickLabel').eq(i).text(ticks[i]);
}
```